# Question about the values of a function near a positive limit

Tags: calculus

In Spivak Calculus, the following is stated:

[image]

But as I understand, we don't need $f$ to be continuous at $a$ or even defined at $a$, it is enough that $f$ has a limit $L$ at $a$ and that $L>0$, then we will have the same conclusion, except that we will have $f>0$ for all x satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$, as we don't care about the value of $f$ at $a$.

I'm correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  There are plenty of instances where the theorem (as it is stated for continuous functions) will prove to be useful, which is why it is stated as such.  But yes, you are correct that the theorem could have been stated in terms of limits, and the continuous function theorem above could have been stated as a corollary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, except that you should write "we will have $\color{red}{f(x)}>0$ for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$". However, you are just giving a separate (but closely related) theorem to the one Spivak gives. Your theorem has a weaker hypothesis – you merely require that the limit at $a$ exists rather than requiring $f$ to be continuous there – and a weaker conclusion – there is a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)$ is positive when $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Spivak's theorem allows him to conclude that $f$ is positive on the open interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta$).

If I remember correctly, Spivak uses his theorem as a key step in the proof of the intermediate value theorem. In this context, the sign of $f(a)$ *does* matter.

It might also be worth noting that your theorem is an immediate corollary of Spivak's. If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and is positive, then consider the function $g$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\neq a$, and $g(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$. Applying Spivak's theorem to $g$ yields your theorem. And, as TM Gallagher points out in the comments, you can also derive Spivak's theorem from yours.